# How to set "full texts" as default for phpMyAdmin?

Tags: phpmyadmin

I am using phpMyAdmin v3.4.10.1deb1 to manage some MySQL-Tables on my Ubuntu-Server with fields that have the SQL-format "TEXT". When those fields are displayed, they are truncated by default. I always have to click on the Symbol "←T→" to expand the texts to their full length. But I don't want to do this click on every single query, because this means, that every query hat do be done twice.

I want that "full texts" is default. But I don't find the place where to set this.

Can you help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's the hacky solution (that works for me) but require changing some PMA php files. If you know what you're doing, you can try this:

- in your phpmyadmin folder locate this file: `phpmyadmin/libraries/display_tbl.lib.php`
- in this file locate function called `PMA_displayTable_checkConfigParams`
- in the beginning of this function add the line below:

```
    if (!isset($_REQUEST['display_text'])) $_REQUEST['display_text'] = 'F';
```

This would enable the "full text" by default allowing you to switch back to the "partial text" mode.

Please mind that i was testing this on a slightly different PMA version (3.5.2.2), so the function/file names might be different.

Comment: This workaround works fine! In my Version of phpMyAdmin there is this line: `$_SESSION['tmp_user_values']['query'][$sql_md5]['display_text'] = 'P';` I had to replace the `P` at the end by `F`. But it is in the same function in the same file as you described.

Comment: It's dangerous to do this kind of undocumented changes because it may affect something totally unrelated somewhere else. Change only if you understand the entire codebase.

Comment: In Version 4.7.6, change `line 4136` in `phpmyadmin/libraries/DisplayResults.php` to read: `$query['pftext'] = self::DISPLAY_FULL_TEXT;`

Comment: They should make it possible to change this without diving into code.  A "Make default" button would have made sense.  I mean 6 years later these code-based solutions are outdated anyway

Answer (score 39):

I have an option in the phpMyAdmin: `Settings > Main Panel > Browse Mode` called: `Limit column characters` where you can change the default limit of characters (50). But I don't believe you can set it to NOT limit by default...

Starting from phpMyAdmin 5, follow the comment below from Alan Dev : Home -> General settings -> More settings -> Main panel -> Browse mode -> Limit column characters

Comment: Thank you. I did set this limit to 100000. This should be enough. But now I have no longer the possibility to truncate the texts if I don't need them in full length.

Comment: looks like you need to decide whether you want it or not :-)

Comment: I did decide: I want "full texts" as a default. But I don't want to miss the possibility to truncate the texts. As I said in my question: "I want that 'full texts' is default." I did not say: "I want to completely dispense with 'truncated texts'."

Comment: it is impossible if one does not configure its PHPMyAdmin to use pma database to store configuration

Comment: I can't find this limit column characters option in the latest version...

Comment: Home -> General settings -> More settings -> Main panel -> Browse mode -> Limit column characters

Comment: For me it is at `/prefs_forms.php?form=Main#tab_Browse`

Answer (score 10):

**FIRST: Don't change core files if it is not necessary.**

To achieve this in PMA version 4.5.4.1 you just have to add this line to your *config.inc.php*:

```
if ( !isset($_REQUEST['pftext'])) $_REQUEST['pftext'] = 'F';
```

This will always set the results to FULL TEXT per default, and you can switch over if you need to partial

Comment: Just a note: In contrast to other answers **this** actually works. I use PMA v4.7.4. So on a localhost you just edit the file: `C:\xampp\phpMyAdmin\config.inc.php` as noted above.

Comment: Thank you. Still works in v4.9.5. I'm using the Ubuntu package of phpmyadmin so I created a file called fulltexts.php under /etc/phpmyadmin/conf.d with the code given by @Greg which keeps the change completely separate from the config.inc.php and should survive upgrades easier.

Answer (score 10):

Change limit of column characters

```
Select "Browse" option of any table
Select Settings gear icon at top right corner
Change character limit in "Limit column characters box" according to your need
Press Apply
```

Comment: You obviously did not understand my question. I asked for full texts as default and I still wanted to be able to toggle between truncated text and full text. Btw: You are a little bit late with your answer. I asked this question 6 years ago.

Comment: I updated answer and I know you asked 6 years ago but when I searched on Google regarding truncated column characters this 6 years old link pops up at first place. So I was looking easy answer. And I am not using 6 years old PhpMyAdmin but using latest. Accepted answer doesn't work with latest version. Definitely my answer was not for you because you are waiting for 6 years. Anyway I answered my findings for others who are using latest version.

Comment: The question is now 9 years old, but still relevant, and this answer by @Zeeshan was/is a valid answer to "How to set "full texts" as default for phpMyAdmin?". I needed *this* answer. As a bonus, this answer tells us that the feature doesn't need to be set globally, which would be a pain in the opposite direction. I understand the OP wanted to toggle. We can toggle from this new table-specific partial limit to full length. For more versatility in a future version, database-specific or global defaults, create an Issue for an Enhancement request.

Answer (score 1):

The equivalent patch for current stable version (4.5.0):

```
diff --git a/libraries/DisplayResults.class.php b/libraries/DisplayResults.class.php
index e435a21..7129c15 100644
--- a/libraries/DisplayResults.class.php
+++ b/libraries/DisplayResults.class.php
@@ -4101,7 +4101,9 @@ class PMA_DisplayResults
         } elseif (empty($query['pos'])) {
             $query['pos'] = 0;
         }
-
+        if (!isset($_REQUEST['pftext'])) {
+            $_REQUEST['pftext'] = self::DISPLAY_FULL_TEXT;
+        }
         if (PMA_isValid(
             $_REQUEST['pftext'],
             array(
```

Answer (score 1):

[Dziad Borowy's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17836340/8027026) is correct in that you cannot set "no limit".

That being said, all the answers on this thread seem to omit the permanent fix to the maximum number of characters, so here it is:

Go to your PMA server. Find the phpMyAdmin configuration file, `config.inc.php`:

```sh
locate config.inc.php
```

Use your text editor of choice to find the following string:

```
$cfg['LimitChars']
```

Change the value to whatever you desire (default is `50`):

```
$cfg['LimitChars'] = 1000;
```

Write and quit. PMA does not need to be restarted, the change should apply automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Yep, this is very annoying.

The answer (3) above pointed me in the right direction but the routine names have changed since his reply.

I am using WAMP with version: 4.5.5 of PHPMyAdmin.

1) Open file "DisplayResultsClass.php" which is located in the "C:/WAMP/PHPMyAdmin/libraries".

2) Search for "private function _getFullOrPartialTextButtonOrLink()"

3) After the opening curly brace "{" FOLLOWING the above line, add the line of code below:-

"if (!isset($_REQUEST['full_text_button'])) _REQUEST['full_text_button'] = 'F';"

This sets the "Full Texts" radio button on.

Close PHPMyAdmin down and reopen it. The default stays (until you update or reinstall WAMP or PHPMyAdmin of course! God know why they did not create a default value in a config file. If they did I certainly could not find it.

I was so sick of switching to "Full Texts" each time when clearly this should be the default anyway. It makes my think the author was deliberately trying to wind programmers up.

John

Answer (score 0):

It worked for me in the version `5.0.2` running in a docker container:

1. `docker exec -it [your_container_name] sh`;
2. `apt-get update`;
3. `apt-get install vim`;
4. `vim ./libraries/classes/Display/Results.php`;
5. Press the letter `i` on your keyboard to enter INSERT mode in `vim`;
6. Change the function `_getPartialText` at the bottom of the file as shown below;
7. When finished editing the file, press the `ESC` key. This takes you out of INSERT mode;
8. To save the file, type in a *colon* followed by *wq*. eg. `:wq`;

```php
/**
     * Truncates given string based on LimitChars configuration
     * and Session pftext variable
     * (string is truncated only if necessary)
     *
     * @param string $str string to be truncated
     *
     * @return mixed
     *
     * @access  private
     *
     * @see     _handleNonPrintableContents(), _getDataCellForGeometryColumns(),
     *          _getDataCellForNonNumericColumns
     */
    private function _getPartialText($str)
    {
        $original_length = mb_strlen($str);

        /*
        if ($original_length > $GLOBALS['cfg']['LimitChars']
            && $_SESSION['tmpval']['pftext'] === self::DISPLAY_PARTIAL_TEXT
        ) {
            $str = mb_substr(
                $str,
                0,
                (int) $GLOBALS['cfg']['LimitChars']
            ) . '...';
            $truncated = true;
        } else {
            $truncated = false;
        }
         */

        $truncated = false;

        return [
            $truncated,
            $str,
            $original_length,
        ];
    }
```