# How to set Full Texts ( $_REQUEST['display_text'] = 'F' ) display in the phpMyAdmin 4?

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

As can be seen in the source code ( https://github.com/phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin/tree/master/libraries ) in PhpMyAdmin 4.*, "phpmyadmin/libraries/display_tbl.lib.php" no longer exists. So, it not possible to do what is described here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17838640

If I change it through "Settings > Main Frame > Browse Mode: Limit column characters " the settings are only stored for the session, but I want it to be stored permanently.

How to set full text as default now?